# Matrix: Summing columns and rows conditional on variable name

Tags: r

Let's say i have a simple 6x6 matrix like this one:

```
x <- matrix(1:36, nrow = 6, dimnames = list(c("AUS1","AUS2","AUS3", "AUT1", "AUT2", "AUT3"), c("AUS1","AUS2","AUS3", "AUT1", "AUT2", "AUT3")))

     AUS1 AUS2 AUS3 AUT1 AUT2 AUT3
AUS1    1    7   13   19   25   31
AUS2    2    8   14   20   26   32
AUS3    3    9   15   21   27   33
AUT1    4   10   16   22   28   34
AUT2    5   11   17   23   29   35
AUT3    6   12   18   24   30   36
```

The letters stand for a country (AUS as Australia) and the number behind for a sector. Now, i want to sum every column but on the condition that only values are taken from rows that do not come from the same country. For example, the sum of the first column (AUS1) should only contain values of the rows AUT1, AUT2 and AUT3. Same goes for the columns of AUS2 and AUS3.
The sum of the column AUT1 should then only include values from the rows AUS1, AUS2, and AUS3.

Since my tables are much larger than this, i cannot simply select the individual rows.

I was thinking of a function that matches part of the column names with parts of the row names. If they contain the same three letters, the value is not included in the sum.

Comment: Are you after `sapply(split(as.data.frame.table(x), ~ Var2), \(a) with(a, sum(Freq[substr(Var1, 1, 3) != substr(Var2, 1, 3)])))`?  You've described your problem reasonably clearly but having the expected output would be additionally helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Let me try to explain: In the end, i need on value per column. This should be the sum of the column. However, the sum differs for the columns. It should only include the values of the rows that do not start with the same letters as the column. So, for the first column (AUS1), the sum should only take values into account of the rows: AUT1, AUT2, and AUT3. Same goes to column 2 and 3. For column 4 (AUT1), it should only consider values of rows that do not include "AUT". Thus, only the rows: AUS1, AUS2, and AUS3. I hope paints a clear picture.

Comment: My original matrix is 2490x2490 large including 43 different countries (letter combination) and 56 sectors (numbers) for each country. I need a function, that gives me a value for every single column (letter combination + number) which is the sum of that column excluding the rows, that start with the same letter combination.

Comment: Thanks I (believe I) understood your problem - you'll notice below that two of the suggested solutions give different results - this is why providing your expected output is a good idea as it allows people to see that their solution arrives at the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another base R way :

```
matched_sum <- function(dfr){
    matched_col <- function(col_id) {
        col_pattern <- gsub("[0-9]", "", colnames(dfr[col_id]))
        dfr[grepl(col_pattern, rownames(x)),col_id] <- NA
        return(dfr[col_id])
    }
    new_col <- lapply(1:ncol(dfr), matched_col)
    new_dfr <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, new_col)
    colSums(new_dfr, na.rm = TRUE)
}

# Your data frame. You can use as.data.frame(x) in case x is not a data frame 
x
     AUS1 AUS2 AUS3 AUT1 AUT2 AUT3
AUS1    1    7   13   19   25   31
AUS2    2    8   14   20   26   32
AUS3    3    9   15   21   27   33
AUT1    4   10   16   22   28   34
AUT2    5   11   17   23   29   35
AUT3    6   12   18   24   30   36

# Apply the function to x
matched_sum(x)

AUS1 AUS2 AUS3 AUT1 AUT2 AUT3 
  15   33   51   60   78   96
```

### What the function does

1. `col_pattern <- gsub("[0-9]", "", colnames(dfr[col_id]))` finds a pattern in each column name. The pattern is any string other than numbers. For example : the pattern in "AUS1" is "AUS".
2. `dfr[grepl(col_pattern, rownames(x)),col_id] <- NA` assigns NA to any row in the column that has pattern found in the 1st step. For example, the first column after this step will become:

```
    AUS1
AUS1   NA
AUS2   NA
AUS3   NA
AUT1    4
AUT2    5
AUT3    6
```

3. `lapply(1:ncol(dfr), matched_col)` apply the 1st step and the 2nd step to each column in the data frame.
4. `do.call(cbind.data.frame, new_col)` binds all columns (that already has NA in the selected rows) to a data frame. For example, if the input is `x` that you provides, after this step it will become:

```
     AUS1 AUS2 AUS3 AUT1 AUT2 AUT3
AUS1   NA   NA   NA   19   25   31
AUS2   NA   NA   NA   20   26   32
AUS3   NA   NA   NA   21   27   33
AUT1    4   10   16   NA   NA   NA
AUT2    5   11   17   NA   NA   NA
AUT3    6   12   18   NA   NA   NA
```

5. `colSums(new_dfr, na.rm = TRUE)` sums all non-NA values in each column in the data frame created in the 4th step.

In case you want to keep the matrix structure for you data, you can use this:

```
matched_sum_mat <- function(mat){
    matched_col <- function(col_id) {
        col_pattern <- gsub("[0-9]", "", dimnames(mat)[[2]][col_id])
        mat[grepl(col_pattern, dimnames(mat)[[1]]),col_id] <- NA
        return(mat[,col_id])
    }
    new_col <- lapply(1:ncol(mat), matched_col)
    new_mat <- do.call(cbind, new_col)
    colnames(new_mat) <- colnames(mat)
    colSums(new_mat, na.rm = TRUE)
}

# Apply to x as a matrix

matched_sum_mat(x)

AUS1 AUS2 AUS3 AUT1 AUT2 AUT3 
  15   33   51   60   78   96
```

### Updates

In case you want an *exact match* between a column name and a row name, such as between "AUS1" in the column names and "AUS1" (instead of "AUS") in the row names, one of several ways to get it is as follows:

```
# Option 1
matched_name_location <- lapply(
   colnames(x), 
   function(a_col_name) rownames(x) %in% a_col_name) |> 
   unlist() |> 
   which()
x[matched_name_location] <- NA

# The result
     AUS1 AUS2 AUS3 AUT1 AUT2 AUT3
AUS1   NA    7   13   19   25   31
AUS2    2   NA   14   20   26   32
AUS3    3    9   NA   21   27   33
AUT1    4   10   16   NA   28   34
AUT2    5   11   17   23   NA   35
AUT3    6   12   18   24   30   NA
```

Another option is to use `==` instead of `%in%` :

```
# Option 2
matched_name_location <- lapply(
   colnames(x), 
   function(a_col_name) rownames(x) == a_col_name) |> 
   unlist() |> 
   which()
x[matched_name_location] <- NA
```

`%in%` gives the same result as `==` does in this case because `a_col_name` is a single name. If multiple names are used, the order of the names is ignored in `%in%`, but not in `==`. For example:

```
y <- c("AUS1", "AUS2" ,"AUS3", "AUT1", "AUT2", "AUT3")
y %in% c("AUS2","AUS1")
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

y == c("AUS2","AUS1")
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Another option is to use `grepl`.

```
# Option 3
matched_name_location <- lapply(
   colnames(x), 
   function(a_col_name) grepl(a_col_name, rownames(x))) |> 
   unlist() |> 
   which()
x[matched_name_location] <- NA
```

The last one is used to find the pattern *within* a string. So, for example, it `grepl("AUS1", "AUS10")` returns `TRUE`, whereas each of `"AUS1" %in% "AUS10"` and `"AUS1" == "AUS10"` returns `FALSE`.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer. It solved my question. When i ran the function the first time, i got the error message:

Error in colSums(new_mat, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

but i changed the 1 to a 2 within this line: new_col <- lapply(1:ncol(mat), matched_col), because my first column is the Code (AUS1, AUS2, etc) for the rows. 

Is there a quick way to adjust the function to just find matches (AUS1-AUS1 rather than AUS1 - AUS)? This is a very useful function and i most likely will be able to use it in the future for various datasets.

Comment: I'm really glad it helped. As for your question, I have updated my answer to answer it. Please have a check.

Comment: Quickly catching up on this one: The code has worked greatly. However, i tried the code for the exact match (option 1) and i recieved a error message saying: 

` Error in which(unlist(lapply(colnames(inter_industry.list), function(a_col_name) rownames(inter_industry.list) %in%  : 
  argument to 'which' is not logical`. 

I believe the code has to be embeded in a function, but i am also still quite new in using R to figure out where specifically the problem is.

Comment: It's highly likely that the problem comes from the data structure. The function in `Option 1` is intended to work on `x` as a matrix or a data.frame. I suspect that `inter_industry.list` that you used is a `list`, not a `matrix` or a `data.frame`. I tried this and got the exactly same error as yours: 
`lapply(colnames(as.list(x)),  function(a_col_name) rownames(x) %in% a_col_name) |>unlist() |> which()`

Comment: It works now. But i realised a different problem. I wrote in my initial post, that the columnnames have to match the rownames. I did not realised that my first column is called "Code" with the initial rownames "AUS1", "AUS2", and so on. The true row names are just 1,2, and so on. This changes the entire post. It is probably better to write a new post about it right? Because it changes all the answers as well. Really sorry for that.

Comment: Oh OK. Yes, please write a new question for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R way. It runs three loops but since the first two (`lapply` loops) are on row and column names, those two shouldn't take much processing time.
Then the real work is done in a `Map` loop, calling `rowSums` on the subsets of row and column names determined before.

```r
x <- matrix(1:36, nrow = 6, dimnames = list(c("AUS1","AUS2","AUS3", "AUT1", "AUT2", "AUT3"), c("AUS1","AUS2","AUS3", "AUT1", "AUT2", "AUT3")))

rn <- unique(gsub("\\d", "", rownames(x)))
rows <- lapply(rn, grep, rownames(x))
cols <- lapply(rn, grep, colnames(x), invert = TRUE)

Map(\(r, c) rowSums(x[r, c]), rows, cols)
#> [[1]]
#> AUS1 AUS2 AUS3 
#>   75   78   81 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> AUT1 AUT2 AUT3 
#>   30   33   36
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

**using data.table**

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(as.data.frame.table(x))

dt[which(substr(Var1, 1, 3) != substr(Var2, 1, 3)), .(sum = sum(Freq)), by = Var2]
```

**use by = Var2 for "rowSums", but you can use by = Var1 if you need the "colSums"*

**output**

```
#    Var2 sum
# 1: AUS1  15
# 2: AUS2  33
# 3: AUS3  51
# 4: AUT1  60
# 5: AUT2  78
# 6: AUT3  96
```

**data as provided by OP**

```
x <- matrix(1:36, nrow = 6, dimnames = list(c("AUS1","AUS2","AUS3", "AUT1", "AUT2", "AUT3"), c("AUS1","AUS2","AUS3", "AUT1", "AUT2", "AUT3")))
```